# Reformatting scraped data using Python Selenium Webdriver.

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I want to extract all the names of the brands on the webpage and paste it into an excel (xlsx) file. The code I've used is:

```
browser.get("https://www.bluesign.com/industry/manufacturers/references.html")
time.sleep(2)
item_list_new=[]
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='defaultMain']")
item_list_new.append(link.text)
print(link.text)

links_list_dict = {"shows":item_list_new}
df_links_list = pd.DataFrame(links_list_dict)
df_links_list.to_excel("bluesign.xlsx")
```

The problem is the output (brand names) appear to be in a single row, single column. I want it to appear in different rows. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use:

```
>>> df_links_list = pd.DataFrame(links_list_dict).T #Transpose
```

for example:

```
>>> a = {"N":["a","b","c","d"]}
>>> c = pd.DataFrame(a).T
>>>c
Out[10]: 
       0  1  2  3
   N   a  b  c  d
```

if you need without header and index you can use:

```
>>> df_links_list.to_excel('file.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```